# Using Histogram LabelingFunction How do you limit the ticks to 3 digits

Tags: output-formatting, histograms

```
Histogram[
  RainYr, {1}, CDF, 
  PlotLabel -> "Cumulative Distribution of Rainfall in Tuscon, Arizon", 
  LabelingFunction -> Above, AxesLabel -> {"Yearly RainFall inches"}
]
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: does LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Round[#, .001], Above] &) or LabelingFunction -> (Placed[NumberForm[N@#, {4,3}], Above] &) give what you need?

Comment: Can you post your RainYr? An easy way to do that is with `CloudPut[..., "Permissions"->"Public"]`

Answer (score 1):

Like @KGLR said,

```
wd=WeatherData[Tucson   city, "TotalPrecipitation", {{2005}, {2019}, "Day"}]
Histogram[wd,{1},CDF,PlotLabel->"Cumulative Distribution of Rainfall in Tuscon, Arizon",FrameLabel->{"Yearly RainFall inches"},
ImagePadding->10,PlotRangePadding->Scaled[.1],
LabelingFunction->(Placed[Text@NumberForm[N@#,{2,1}],Above]&)
]
```

[image]

If there are too many bars, one option is to use `Tooltip` instead:

```
wd = WeatherData[
  Entity["City", {"Tucson", "Arizona", "UnitedStates"}], 
  "TotalPrecipitation", {{1995}, {2019}, "Year"}];

Histogram[wd, {1}, CDF, 
 PlotLabel -> "Cumulative Distribution of Rainfall in Tuscon, Arizon",
  FrameLabel -> {"Yearly RainFall inches"},
 ImagePadding -> 10, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
 LabelingFunction -> Tooltip
 ]
```

[image]